# jQuery Tools - Range Input API

Tags: api, jquery-tools

Resorting to SO since it is impossible to find any sort of contact information on jquerytools.org, and the site will not let me log in to the forums to post there.

I'm using Range Input and am trying to call the API to add in arrows at each end of the slider to perform step ups/downs.

Here is my js code that loads the Range Input:

```
        var scroll = jQuery('#river-scroll');

        jQuery("#video-river-range").rangeinput({
            value: <?php echo $rangeValue ?>,
            speed: 0,
            progress: true,
            onSlide: function(ev, step) {
                scroll.css({left: -step});
            },
            change: function(e, i) {
                scroll.animate({left: -i}, "fast");
            }
        });
```

Following the doc on their site, I should be able to access the API via:

```
var api = jQuery("#video-river-range").data("rangeinput");
```

And then subsequently use this:

```
function advanceStep() {
    api.next();
}
```

Alas, not working. I'm given:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<A> has no method 'next'
```

Advice appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Gee, nevermind. Apparently the api methods 'next' and 'prev' which are documented on the site don't actually exist.

Comment: And I'm asking myself why not... really needed those functions, that's stupid :P